# Comparing two arrays of strings c++

Tags: c++

Ok thank you everyone for your comments. I have fixed much of it.  Now when I compile it, it gives me an error on line in main where I call getPercent() saying this :

```
 error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘std::string*’ for argument ‘3’ 
        to ‘void getPercent(int, std::string*, std::string*, std::string*)’
```

What can fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


string getYours()
{
   cout << "Enter your DNA sequence: " ;
   string sequence;
   cin >> sequence;
   return sequence;

}

int getNumber()
{
   cout << "Enter the number of potential relatives: ";
   int number;
   cin >> number;
   cout << endl;
   return number;

}

void getNames(int number, string name[])
{

   for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
   {
      cout << "Please enter the name of relative #" << i + 1 << ": ";
      cin >> name[i];


   }


}

void getSequences(int number, string name[], string newsequence[])
{
   cout << endl;

   for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
   {
      cout << "Please enter the DNA sequence for " << name[i] << ": ";
      cin >> newsequence[i];


   }

}

void getPercent(int number, string name[], string sequence[],
                string newsequence[])
{
   cout << endl;
   int count = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
   {

      if (sequence[i] == newsequence[i])
         count = count + 10;
      cout << "Percent match for " << name[i] << ": " << count << "%";

   }


}

int main()
{
   string sequence = getYours();
   int number = getNumber();
   string name[50];
   string newsequence[50];
   getNames(number, name);
   getSequences(number, name, newsequence);
   getPercent(number, name, sequence, newsequence);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why using raw arrays instead of `std::array` or `std::vector` in first place?

Comment: I havent learned about that yet , I'm workin with what I know :3

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you should initialise your `count` variable to 0 and use a higher warning level in your compiler.

Comment: @OdieB Well, you can't use raw arrays with unspecified size. You either need to pass it along with an additional parameter, or provide a size specifier in the parameter declaration (not very useful, from a generic programming POV). That's why we are rather using the mentioned containers. You can easily learn how to use them from the examples given in the [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp).

Comment: I am using raw arrays, I'm looking at the line:
if (sequence[i] == newsequence[i])
in GetPercent- it is not comparing the two because they are not the same type. How can I compare the first value from sequence to the first value in newsequence? and the second to the second? and so on..
I do know that each sequence will have only 10 characters in it.

Comment: @OdieB _"... it is not comparing the two because they are not the same type."_ Huh?? They actually are? Also you forgot to initialise `count` properly.

Comment: Never do using namespace std;

Comment: @OdieB Also `void getYours()` definition is merely as good as a NOP. Completely useless and nonsensical.

Comment: Oh it is comparing the same. Well i thought sequence was just a string, and that newsequence was an array of strings?

Comment: @OdieB Have you actually tried running this through your compiler? It would tell you if the two were of different types.

Answer (score 3):

A few problems:

1. `getYours()` has no side effects. You probably meant to assign to the string `sequence` in `main()`, but instead are assigning to a local variable that will be destroyed as it goes out of scope.
2. No error checking for too many elements in your arrays (try using a `std::vector`).
3. You stop at `10` in `getPercent()` instead of `number` elements (if that's what you wanted).
4. In `getPercent()`, `count` is not initialized to 0. Something seems strange about the logic in `getPercent()`, so I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do.
5. The arguments `sequence` and `newsequence` in `getPercent()` are actually the same type, and would compile fine.

And probably a few other things I've overlooked.

Comment: Good answer. Though be prepared (and not dissapointed) to loose your upvote points, when the question is deleted. I will vote so, as soon it's closed. That question is of no value for future research in it's current form.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Meh. If I can help the OP be a better programmer, so be it.

Comment: Good attitude. We're not a personal help desk though. The site is meant as a repository for long term purposes and view. I was one of the upvotes BTW. Anyway answering such questions is a bit of problematic, since it gives help vampires a conception, that they could come here to ask (which is definitely unwanted).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Would this match the Code Review site better, or not?

Comment: @Numeri Sadly not. Code Review is for *working* code. Considering the compilation error it wouldn't fit! (Though the format of this answer does kinda fit in CR)

Comment: @TopinFrassi OK, just checking.  I was wondering what Code Review was looking for in questions... Thanks!

Comment: @Numeri We got a very [handy page](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for that.

Comment: @Mast Heh.. probably should have read that, but oh well! :) thanks!

Comment: @owacoder you may post answers like this at CodeReview if you want, and they will not be deleted :)

Comment: @owacoder Exactly right, as help-vampires should not get our blood.